# Calculate the ForeignKey type Percentage (individual) Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to calculate the percentage of all car types using Django ORM, or group by all of the cars on the basis of their types, and calculate the percentage. I've multiple solutions but they are old-fashioned and itrative. I am going to use this query over the dashboard where already multiple queries calculating different analytics. I don't want to compromise on performance, that's why I prefer the single query. Here is the structure of my tables (written) on Django:

```
class CarType:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Car:
    car_type = models.ForeignKey(CarType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have a utility function that has the following details:

- input => cars: (Queryset) of cars Django.
- output => list of all car_types (dictionaries) having percentage.

  - [{'car_type': 'car01', 'percentage': 70, 'this_car_type_count': 20}, ...]

What I've tried so far:

```
cars.annotate(
        total=Count('pk')
    ).annotate(
        car_type_name=F('car_type__name')
    ).values(
        'car_type_name'
    ).annotate(
        car_type_count=Count('car_type_name'),
        percentage=Cast(F('car_type_count') * 100.0 / F('total'), FloatField()),
    )
```

But, this solution is giving 100% on all car_types. I know this weird behavior is because of the `values()` I'm using, but I've kinda stuck it here.

Answer (score 0):

`F('total')` will be the count of cars within each group (each car type) not the total count of the whole table. This is why you always get 100%. You can achieve what you want in two queries:

```
total = cars.count()

cars.annotate(
    car_type_name=F('car_type__name')
).values(
    'car_type_name'
).annotate(
    car_type_count=Count('car_type_name'),
    percentage=Cast(F('car_type_count') * 100.0 / total, FloatField())
)
```

If you really want to do this in one query instead of two, the computation of total will need to be a window function instead of a regular aggregate.